# Redirect URL with query string to subdomain, maintaining query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a Drupal 6 installation that runs web services.  So if someone goes to www.example.com/services/json?method=views.get&view_name="test", they get the proper encoded response.

I'm doing some maintenance work on it, so I created a sub-domain and copied everything over to it, and I want to redirect all requests to the subdomain while the main one is being worked on. So when a request comes in, it now needs to go to old.example.com/services/json?method=views.get, etc.

I've tried a few ways, but nothing works. It just goes crazy, saying I have too many redirects and then the page fails to load.

A few things I've tried:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /services/json(.*)$ http://old.example.com/services/json$1
```

Or

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/services/json(.*)$ http://old.example.com/services/json$1
```

Here is how the folder structure looks.

public_html - top folder with the following inside it:
-main drupal site files with the .htaccess file I'm editing
-old (this is the folder that contains the subdomain files, a copy of the main site, minus some stuff on its .htaccess file)

I suspect that structure might have something to do with it, but I have no idea.

EDIT: More info about what redirect rules are in the .htaccess files.

Top main domain folder:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/services/json(.*)$ http://old.example.com/services/json$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In the subdomain folder (I've removed most of the other rules during my testing):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `.htaccess` file / Apache config isn't also affecting the subdomain?  Requests that come in on the subdomain would match your redirect, as well, and create that loop.

Comment: I suspect you're right. How do I get it to ignore the subdomain and subdomain folder? See the edits I made to the question.